# How to return a spread operator in a map arrow function in one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

What I need to do is map over an Array and set a value to false on all of the objects. This was my first shot:

```
data = data.map((item) => {
  item.active = false;
  return item;
})
```

Works! But then there is Eslint, [no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign). So I had to find something else. After some googling I found the spread operator! Awesome! I created this masterpiece:

```
data = data.map((item) => {
  return {...item, active: false}
})
```

Looks cool and works as well. But then there is Eslint again, [arrow-body-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style). ok fine I will return the object on the same line:

```
data = data.map(item => {...item, active: false});
```

Dosn't work! :'( Am I missing something?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I don't think this closing is right. The real problem wasn't returning an object from a lambda.

Comment: @DenysSéguret It's unclear what the real problem is and what the OP really needs, the whole question he asked revolves around mapping an array to an array of new objects.

Comment: The real problem is how to fix the linter problems

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When returning a literal object from an arrow function construct (a lambda), you have to wrap it in parentheses so that it's seen as an expression:

```
data.map(item => ({...item, active: false}));
```

`map` is only useful if you need a different array.

But there's a simpler solution here. You don't have to reassign all items and `data`. You should simply do

```
data.forEach(item => item.active=false)
```

Comment: I knew that I was missing something. Thanks that worked

Comment: That probably still breaks the *no-param-reassign* rule. You should rather do `for (const item of data) item.active = false;`

Comment: Yes it indeed still breaks the rule. but then there is the next one https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax

Comment: Are there any downsides to the first example with wrapped parantheses?